# Extract indices from array meeting a condition in R

Tags: r

Say I have `d<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7)`.  How can I select the indices from d that meet a certain condition such as `x>3` and `x<=6` (i.e. d[4], d[5], d[6], d[7])?

Answer (score 9):

Use `which`

```
> which(d>3 & d<=6)
[1] 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: Is the `arr.ind` argument necessary here?

Comment: No,  BUT it is useful to point out its existence. If this were a matrix, arr.ind would be needed for full information.

Comment: Thanks, this works fine.  However, I have a huge dataset and will be calling this command many times.  How is the performance of which and are there any ways to speed it up?

Comment: I already edited my answer, after reading your comments I realized `arr.ind` is not necessary here :D

Answer (score 0):

Minor: c() creates a vector, which is similar to but not exactly an array.

You can create a logical vector an use it to access `d`.

```
d[d>3 & d<=6] # the operators return logical vectors, [] extracts 
              # only the TRUE values
```